# WooCommerce how to perform conditional checks for custom categories

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce store and I'm trying to add prefixes to the order number based on if the order contains a product within one of two different categories.

The two categories are `Customs` and `Refurbished`.

This code works perfectly if the order only contains a Custom or a Refurbished product, but the problem occurs when an order contains both a Custom and Refurbished product. This code will just apply the prefix of `CPC-` or `REF-` depending on whatever item is first in the order.

I want to make it so that if an order contains both of these categories, that the system defaults to adding the Custom prefix of `CPC-` but I can't figure out how to do that.

Below is my code, look for the  to find my failed attempt to fix this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
      
   // 1. Get order object
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  
   // 2. Initialize $cat_in_order variable
   $cat_in_order = '';
  
   // 3. Get order items and loop through them...
   // ... if product in category, edit $cat_in_order
   $items = $order->get_items(); 
     
   foreach ( $items as $item ) {
      $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
      if ( has_term( 'refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
         $cat_in_order = 'refurbished';
         break;
      }  elseif ( has_term( 'customs', 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
         $cat_in_order = 'customs';
         break;
//
//  Here's my attempt to fix this, but it's not working 
//
      }  elseif ( has_term( 'customs', 'product_cat', $product_id ) && has_term( 'refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
         $cat_in_order = 'customs';
         break;
      }
   }
  
   // 4. Add Order Prefix if in Customs Category 
   if ( $cat_in_order == 'refurbished' ) {
        $prefix = 'REF-';
        $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
        return $new_order_id;
   } elseif ( $cat_in_order == 'customs' ) {
        $prefix = 'CPC-';
        $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
        return $new_order_id;
   } else {
       return $order_id;
   }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set this up, but since you're already using `if` statement, I'll take the same approach!

The simple answer would be to add another condition to your `if/elseif` statements.

So replace your first conditional check with this line:

```php
if (has_term('refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id) && !has_term('customs', 'product_cat', $product_id))
```

Replace the second condition with this one:

```php
elseif (has_term('customs', 'product_cat', $product_id) && !has_term('refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id))
```

And the last condition stays intact!

```php
elseif (has_term('customs', 'product_cat', $product_id) && has_term('refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id))
```

---

So the entire conditional section of your snippet would be something like this:

```php
foreach ($items as $item) 
{
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    if 
    (
        has_term('refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id) 
        && 
        !has_term('customs', 'product_cat', $product_id)
    )
    {
        $cat_in_order = 'refurbished';
    } 
    elseif 
      (
        has_term('customs', 'product_cat', $product_id) 
        && 
        !has_term('refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id)
      )
    {
        $cat_in_order = 'customs';
    } 
    elseif 
      (
        has_term('customs', 'product_cat', $product_id) 
        && 
        has_term('refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id)
      ) 
    {
        $cat_in_order = 'customs';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from answer of Ruvee there is some tuning we can perform.

The problem is implicity you set a hierarchy in your choice.

So if Custom attribute is set this has precedence.

in this case we can simply the code in this way.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
$product_id = $item->get_product_id();
if (  has_term('customs', 'product_cat', $product_id) ){
    $cat_in_order = 'customs';

} elseif ( has_term('refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id) )  {
    $cat_in_order = 'refurbished';
}  else {
    
    // Manage the exception!
}
```

}

So if Custom is true elseif is not processed and we don't need to set other conditions.

However, pay attantion on the break usage, is not needed  in if / elseif statement, and it's wrong.

Comment: Just to let you know: 1- Your suggested code would fail **if there are more categories or the order of the categories are different than the logic you suggested**. What if, in the future, they decide to extend their logic and add more categories? Again your suggested code would fail, It's not extendible! 2- Using `break` in the `if` statement would be incorrect and it was a typo from copying/pasting the code from the question and I deleted it from my answer.

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch for the tip! So if I understand correctly it's that since the code was already seeing that one condition was already true, so it doesn't bother processing the other elseif/else statements. Good to know. I'm still pretty green when it comes to PHP and stuff like this helps out a lot with my understanding of the language.

Comment: Ruvee, ops, I'm not catch the "break" is just in your code, I supposed is in the original one (basing on you contribution it's clear to me you know the break is not needed :-) ). Sorry for my mistake.

Coming to the point, I don't agree, beacuse also your code is not extendible easly.
I mean: if some categories has different precedences, the code will be arranged to take care of this hierarchy, but also your.

A hierarchy could be represented in the code (functional) or by a database (setting explicity the precedence), only using a database a future code tuniing isn't need.

Comment: @PressXtoJason, PHP use many rules like C and Java, so if else/if is alway mutually exclusive.

But Ruvue is right when says if other categories will be addedd you need to modify the code.
The only way to avoid this rewriting is transform your code using a db (or some data structure) that store the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
      $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
      if ( has_term( 'customs', 'product_cat', $product_id ) && has_term( 'refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
         $cat_in_order = 'customs';
         
      }
      elseif ( has_term( 'refurbished', 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
         $cat_in_order = 'refurbished';
         
      }  elseif ( has_term( 'customs', 'product_cat', $product_id )) {
         $cat_in_order = 'customs';
         ;

      }  
   }
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.